# Add a Contact Us page to Moodle

Tags: php, moodle

I want to add a Contact Us page to Moodle and I used the below code. But this is not working, I get a completely blank page.

Can anybody point out the fault of this piece of code? I'm using Moodle 2.5 and I placed this file on the root directory of Moodle.

```
// The number of lines in front of config file determine the // hierarchy of files. 
require_once(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/../config.php');

$PAGE->set_context(get_system_context());
$PAGE->set_pagelayout('standard');
$PAGE->set_title("Contact US");
$PAGE->set_heading("Contact");
$PAGE->set_url($CFG->wwwroot.'/contact.php');

echo $OUTPUT->header();

// Actual content goes here
echo "Hello World";

echo $OUTPUT->footer();
```

Comment: Could you provide a more accurate problem description than 'this is not working'? What's the result that you get? Do you have any errors?

Comment: Yes Carpetsmoker. I kept this script on the root directory and when i go to that file localhost/tha/moodle/contact.php, it does not show the header or footer or anything.

Comment: And what did it show? A completely white page?

Comment: Yes. Nothing more than that.

Comment: You may have an error in your page, the syntax looks fine, but it could be a runtime error. Try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'on');` at the top of the page (just below the opening `<?php`), and check if you get an error. If you don't, you may also want to check your server's error log (to be sure).

Comment: It shows Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\tha/../config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\kolitha\moodle\about.php on line 5. which config.php file should i select? current theme's config file file or config file on root directory?

Comment: I got it corrected. I selected root directory's config.php file. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the main menu block rather than creating code - http://docs.moodle.org/25/en/Main_menu_block

- Go to your front page
- Turn editing on
- Add a block and choose main menu

You can then add a contact us page and then grab the url.

Comment: Thanks Russel for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
require_once(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/../config.php');
```

This gets `config.php` from the parent directory. You mentioned you put your contact form in the root directory, so this is obviously not correct, since it's one level above Moodle's root directory.

You're using `dirname` twice, which is not what you want, you only want to use this once.

It would seem that `config.php` is in Moodle's root directory, so this line should be:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/config.php');
```

Which is really the same thing as just:

```
require_once('./config.php');
```

Comment: require_once(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/config.php'); is not working for me. I tested it. I just used require_once('config.php'); Don't know whether wrong or correct. I'm new to Moodle.

Comment: @koli Ack, I missed the double `dirname()` function call >.< It's too late for StackOverflow....